# IV estimation for when instrument is independent of the outcome

Tags: causality, independence, linear-algebra, instrumental-variables, underdetermined

So I came across [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/econometrics/comments/j71im8/if_z_is_independent_of_outcome_y_can_we_still_use/) and have some use for it in my own work.

**Recap of Original Question:** In the canonical IV setting, suppose we have a data-generating model $Z\rightarrow X\rightarrow Y$ (where $X$, $Y$ are confounded, and instrument $Z$), suppose we have $Z\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$. Can we still use $Z$ as an instrument to retrieve the ground-truth, causal solution?

**My Remarks:** After giving some thought to it, here is what I think:

- Yes, $Z$ can still be used as an instrument, but (for the linear case) the problem will be under-determined and only one of the infinitely many solutions will be the true, causal solution. An example that makes this clear is the following:
  $$
  \mathbf{X} = \mathbf{Z}\mathbf{K}_{\theta} + \mathbf{N}_X\\
  \mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\theta + 0.1\mathbf{N}_Y
  $$
  where the rows of $\mathbf{K}_{\theta}$ span $\text{Null}(\theta)$. And $N_X$, $N_Y$, $Z$ are random normal (exogenous). Here, $Z$ and $Y$ are independent despite $Z\rightarrow X\rightarrow Y$ being the ground truth model. We can include a confounder $H$ here as well, but I left it out for simplicity. Note that in the second stage we will regress $\mathbf{Y}$ from $\hat{\mathbf{X}} := \mathbf{Z}\hat{\mathbf{K}}_{\theta}$ which has the rank $d-1 < d = \text{dim}(\theta)$ (assuming that $X$ is $d$-dimensional). Because of this under-determinedness, using the closed-form linear-regression solution in the second stage here will always yield $\mathbf{0}$, since that is the least-norm solution.
- For the non-linear case, we will still have multiple solutions with just one of them being the ground-truth causal solution. For example, $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ is a solution for the non-linear case, but is not however the ground truth solution.

**My Question:** In both the linear or the non-linear cases, I cannot theoretically formalise (in a general way, without using specific examples as above) how using $Z$ as an instrumental variable in cases where $Z\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$ can at least reduce the size of the hypothesis space. So how do I show what I did in the previous examples more abstractly that there exist many (potentially infinite) solutions to the IV problem, and one of them is indeed the ground-truth, causal solution? I don't even know where to start to be honest.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought the IV $Z$ was *supposed* to be independent of $Y.$ That is, according to Pearl's *Causality*, you must have $(Z\perp\!\!\!\perp Y|S)_{G_{\overline{X}}}$ and not $(Z{\perp\!\!\!\perp}X|S)_G.$ - p. 248.

Comment: @AdrianKeister yes, it is supposed to be *conditionally* independent $(Z\perp\!\!\!\perp Y \mid X)$ and *not* $(Z\perp\!\!\!\perp Y)$. In my example, we have the latter from which it follows that the former will hold as well, so $Z$ is indeed a valid instrument (at least that's how I understand it). The problem, however, with the latter being true is that the IV problem (2nd stage least-squares) will become under-determined as I described in my first example above.